# How can I render an image from a PDF with python as Microsoft Edge is doing?

Tags: python, image, opencv, pdf, imagemagick

So when I produce a JPEG from a PDF with Wand and Python, I can see how some lines of the staff are different size, but when I zoom with MS Edge, they're same size... and I can not find the way of doing it same way.

Wand

[image]

Cairo
[image]

First answer method:

```sh
convert +antialias -density 1200 Betlem.pdf -alpha off -resize 640x -monochrome A_betlem_m_en_vull_anar.png
```

[image: Rasterized image with data loss]

I've tried poppler, pdftocairo, pdf2(png¦svg), inkscape, etc...

```py
pdf = wi(filename = "Betlem.pdf", resolution = 300)
pdfImage = pdf.convert("jpeg")
d = 1
for img in pdfImage.sequence:
   page = wi(image=img)
   page.save(filename="Betlem_" + str(d) + ".jpg")
   d += 1
```

I expect a result where I can see the staff and notes same way of scaling than in Edge (best) or Firefox (great).

As follows the PDF: http://www.xn--estudiantladolaina-lvb.com/partitures/baixa/pdf/26

EDITED:

You can see how it is rendering bad because of errors in the SVG information on the PDF: [image]

Comment: Perhaps they are being rendered at different default densities. Try setting the same density for both. Python Wand uses Imagemagick which in turn uses Ghostscript. Try rendering directly with Ghostscript and set the same density as you render with other tools. Python Wand is Python. So what do you use when you say Wand vs Python?

Comment: Have a zoom on the 1st image and see how the staff lines are different sized. That image is a  JPEG from Wand using the example code, with a resolution of 300. The 2nd is a rasterized image, but as the source is bad sized, the result is bad. I didn't say Wand vs Python, I say ImageMagick vs Cairo...

Comment: 2nd image is not a result from 1st, even same PDF. They are from different tests.

Comment: Using ghostscript obtains better result but even some staff lines are ticker.

Comment: Perhaps the two systems are rending text differently or using different fonts or font metrics. Did you set the density to the same in both systems?

Comment: Well, the main question is about how to renderize as Edge does, with Python... I am just testing every possible way to approximate the rending to the same.

Comment: Only Microsoft knows what they do, unless you can point to more details. But have you been able to set the density and fonts to exactly the same values?

Comment: No, I just used the maximum density possible (1200) and then seems the size is okay, but same problem when downscaling...

Comment: Downsizing how? Your viewer could be handling it differently. Sorry I am not a Windows user so I cannot test your Microsoft Edge. I do not know what else to suggest.

Comment: You just said, Microsoft's software is paid and that's the way they can waste time on best rendering. Firefox is doing it well enough, but still not perfect. Anyway, the question would be: how can I make an algorithm to render SVG without loosing quality (ratio=width/heigh or ratio=height/width).

Comment: You first have to know how Microsoft Edge algorithm works and how any other SVG renderer works and at least you have to use the same density. So first inquire of Edge how it is supposed to work. But the viewer and not the renderer might be the issue. Are you viewing with outputs from the different renderers with the same viewer/display/browser?  I do not think this forum is going to be able to help, unless someone from Microsoft can answer what Edge is doing. Did you tell both renderers to use the same density and same fonts? That is the first thing I would check.

Comment: I never said anything about "paid" software for Edge. What are you getting at? Microsoft is mostly closed software, so not likely you will know what algorithms or techniques they use.

Comment: Please show resulting images from Edge and other software so we can see the difference. You only show Wand and Cairo and do not show what Wand software/code or Cairo code you are using. We cannot see if the same densities and fonts are being used. Also show the original SVG. That way others might be able to test with it.

Comment: Please, if you want to continue this discussion, move it to the chat section.

Comment: Just to say I misswrote the answer. I hadn't said, you said that about Microsoft. I just said an expression as in spain we say: "You said it!". As if you say what I say but you said without same words. I meant that Microsoft is closed software, and etc... because you said is paid software. Just said "you got it!" like if I am happy because you understood me. I mean Edge is rendering better SVG because its algorithm is better. I will attach some snipped screen images and move the chat to chat section. Tomorrow. Thanks by your help!

Comment: Screen snaps won't help. It is important to have the original SVG file and actual output images. Screen snaps will be useful to see how the browser display the rasterized images. Your problem might not be in the rasterized images themselves, but in the way your tools are displaying them. Can you export your rasterized image from MS Edge as an actual PNG or TIFF file and compare that to the rasterized images from the other tools?

Comment: The original PDF is from http://www.estudiantladolçaina.com/uploads/Partitures/A%20betlem%20m%20en%20vull%20anar.pdf

Comment: This is a PDF, not an SVG. Why do you keep talking about SVG?  Where are your rendered output images saved as PNG or TIFF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Imagemagick 6.9.10.55 Q16 Mac OSX and Ghostscript 9.25, I can convert at high quality using supersampling (4x nominal 72 dpi density and resize down by 1/4 to normal scale) as

```
convert -density 288 A_betlem_m_en_vull_anar.pdf -alpha off -resize 25% A_betlem_m_en_vull_anar.png
```

[image]

How does this compare to your MS Edge view? (Download my image and view it).

ADDITION:

Here is the same code in Python Wand, which uses Imagemagick.

## !/bin/python3.7

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='A_betlem_m_en_vull_anar.pdf', resolution=288) as img:
    img.alpha_channel='off'
    img.resize(width=int(0.25*img.width),height=int(0.25*img.height))
    img.save(filename='A_betlem_m_en_vull_anar.png')
```

Comment: Well, thanks at first. It is very cool to know supersampling and resize down method. Sadly, I need to rasterize the image. MS Edge doesn't use anti-alias. Edge is rendering the SVG data from PDF  very cool with big sizes, as IM, Wand and/or GS are doing with 1200dpi (best relation between heigh and weight). I need to rasterize the image and downscale from best looking image (1200dpi). I edit the question adding the result of what I've done by your answer. But I still don't give you the answer correct, because the question was, more deeply: "how can I render an SVG into small size (640x)?".

Comment: I discovered that PDF is being bad rendered by any software. Maybe the SVG information is not correct or it is compatible with anti-alias only. Because when I zoom in (supersampling) I can see defects that makes software algorithms to delete or add some lines...

Comment: What SVG? You provided a PDF. They render with different software. SVG uses RSVG or Inkscape and PDF uses Ghostscript in Imagemagick.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking PDF had SVG information. Really it has Ghostscript. I am trying to replace the font use for music notation with another.

Comment: Fonts are likely imbedded in the PDF. You would need a PDF editor, I suspect.